# It is possible to use Firebase ML Kit in node js (Express js)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-mlkit

I want to use a firebase ML kit in node js. but I don't know it is possible or not.  if it is possible so which package is best in node js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ML Kit is a combination of running on-device ML models on Android and iOS, and an easy way to call Google Cloud ML APIs from those devices. There is no support for ML Kit beyond iOS and Android.

But that doesn't mean you're out of luck.

1. ML Kit's on-device ML models are TensorFlow Lite models, so you can run similar models yourself on every platform that support TFLit.
2. ML Kit's wrappers for Google Cloud ML APIs are precisely that: simple wrappers. You can use the Google Cloud ML API's directly from your Node.js code, using the [GCP  Node.js SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/), instead of the Firebase ML Kit wrappers.